# defining operator for object

Tags: flutter, dart, operators

```
 TotalResponse totalResponse =
                  TotalResponse.fromJson(snapshot.data![0][0]);

              String confirmed = totalResponse.confirmed;
              String recovered = totalResponse.recovered;
              String deaths = totalResponse.deaths;
              String active = (int.parse(confirmed) -
                      int.parse(recovered) -
                      int.parse(deaths))
                  .toString();

              print(snapshot.data![1]);
              List<int> list = snapshot.data![1].toString().codeUnits;
            ;
```

The **operator** '[]' **isn't defined** for the type '**Object**'.
Try defining the operator '[]'

Answer (score 0):

use `doc.data()`to get the data of a document.

```
// if you query multiple document and want to display the first one:
print(querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
// if get one document
print(documentSnapshot.data());
```

> operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

You have an object, not a list, and that operator is not defined for objects.